# How to make different mysql row updates based on a list of keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of online users that I download once per minute... This file does not include the IDs of users that are currently offline...

I need to update both the people who are online and those who are offline in mysql... something like:

```
update online=TRUE where userID in (list of online IDs)
```

then do a

```
update online=FALSE where userID NOT in (list of online IDs)
```

I'm curious if there is an elegant one sql solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IN` operator returns a boolean value so you could say this:

```
update your_table
set online = userID in (list of online IDs)
```

Where, of course, *list of online IDs* will be a comma delimited list of the IDs that are online.